# Switching between 2 states

Tags: c, mplab

I'm using mplab and coding in C.
I have setup my program so it has 2 states.
I want to be able to double tap a button and it swaps between state 1 and 2. I am doing this a very simple way, rather than using switching statements etc.

I have it all set up and working but it's going from state 1 back into state 1 because of the way I've coded it.

Is there a way I can say, if button is double tapped, go into the opposite state? Rather than:

```
if (state == 1)
{
state = 2;
}

if (state == 2)
{
state = 1;
}
```

Of course, this way it is going into state 2 but then jumps into the following code which changes it back into state 1 again.

I know I can put: state = ~state;
But how do I set it so it knows there's only a state 1 and 2?

Heres a bit of my code:

```
if (RC1 == 0) // if button is pressed
{
ButtonPressCounter++; // add 1 to counter
}
__delay_ms(250);
if (RC1 == 0) // if button is pressed again
{
ButtonPressCounter++; // add 1 to counter
}

while (ButtonPressCounter == 2)
{
if (state == 1)
{
state = 2;
}
if (state == 2)
{
state = 1;
}
ButtonPressCounter = 0;
}
```

Comment: `state = (state==1)  ?  2  :  1;` BTW: debounce and flipping the state are two different things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain that code a little please, I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Why do you want to use state `1` and `2` instead of `0` and `1`? Switching between state `0` and `1` is easy: `state = 1 - state;` or `state ^= 1;`

Comment: `state = ~state;` does not switch from `0` to `1` and back, but from `0` to `-1` and back. Do you mean `state = !state;`?

Comment: No reason for 1 and 2 really MikeCAT, I'll change it to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `else` to prevent `if (state == 2)` from being executed when `state == 1`.

```
if (state == 1)
{
    state = 2;
}
else if (state == 2) /* add "else" here */
{
    state = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that